# Hfill not working

Tags: ltablex

[image]

Hey fellas, look at the picture given above. I want (continued) to be completely left aligned, however, leftalign not working in tabularx (ltablex) env. for me, and hence I am using \hfill. Though hfill works to some extent, but doesn't yield a complete left alignment. Any solutions for modifying hill or any other solution to fix this? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{Document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
\toprule\toprule
Some random text & 1,75,650\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Panel A1: AAA}} \\\midrule
Number of observations ... & 1,75,650\\
Delete: ... & (78,420)\\
Delete: ... & (7,104)\\
Final sample & 90,126\\
Delete: & (2,143)\\
Delete: & (8,345)\\
Final sample & 79,638\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Panel A2: AAA}} \\\midrule
Number of observations & 79,638\\
Delete: & (39,540)\\
Delete: & (7,979) \\
Final sample & 32,119 \\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Panel B1: BBB }} \\\midrule
Number of observations  & 1,75,650\\
Delete: & (78,420)\\
Delete: & (47,136)\\
Delete: & (7,178)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Final sample & 42,884\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Panel B2: BBB}} \\\midrule
Number of observations  & 1,75,650\\
Delete: & (78,420)\\
Delete: & (47,136)\\
Delete: & (7,178)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Number of observations  & 1,75,650\\
Delete: & (78,420)\\
Delete: & (47,136)\\
Delete: & (7,178)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Delete: & (32)\\
Final sample & 42,884\\\midrule\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The line which bothers me is this : \bottomrule\hfill\small\textit{(Continued)}\endfoot
                \bottomrule\insertTableNotes\endlastfoot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you speak of `tabularx`: in tabular environments, there's space before and after a column. You can remove it by inserting `@{}` in the corresponding place of the column definitions, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{4cm}{@{}Xr@{}}
\hline
Number & 42\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: table output]

Similar, if you use `\multicolumn`:

```
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{...}
```

Your MWE becomes:

[image: table output]

And in your case of the "Continued" line, use `\multicolumn` instead of `\hfill`:

```
\bottomrule\multicolumn{2}{@{}r@{}}{\small\textit{(Continued)}}\endfoot
```

[image: Continued line]

Comment: very cool. Thanks. I understood the mistake I was making. Thanks a lot.